# Where can I order a cover plate for two light switches and one humidity sensor?

Tags: switch, cover

I've got a bathroom lightswitch with two actual light switches, and one [dewstop](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B003Q6CGKW/ref=oh_aui_search_detailpage?ie=UTF8&psc=1) that goes to the ceiling fan.  The light switches are on the left and middle, and the dewstop is on the right.

Is it possible to order a cover plate online that will cover the drywall?  What would I google/where could I find it?

Comment: It's not clear why a regular 3-gang cover plate, like [this one](https://images.homedepot-static.com/productImages/0ecea20d-db94-467e-836a-6edece631d5a/svn/white-leviton-rocker-switch-plates-r52-pj263-00w-64_1000.jpg) or [this one](https://cdn1.bigcommerce.com/server3900/wlejmk/products/344/images/801/2_toggle_1_decora_rocker_gfci_wall_plate_spv__77249.1348030660.310.310.jpg?c=2) or one of [these](https://www.google.com/search?q=3+gang+cover+plate&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYztGNqJnXAhUB2IMKHTtjAzUQsAQI7QE&biw=1706&bih=851) wouldn't work ...

Comment: Because the right is a different size from the left and middle.

Comment: "gang" is a term I have never seen before, and that is helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You need a two regular/1 decorator 3-gang plate

Your "dewstop" (humidstat) fits what's called a decorator (sometimes called "Decora") wallplate.  So, you need a 3-gang wallplate with regular (toggle) switch openings on the left and center and a decorator opening on the right, such as the Hubbell NP226W depicted below:

[image: Hubbell NP226W]

Comment: Should be readily available, try a proper electrical supply house instead of big-box.  The charm of Decora is that both switches and receptacles (well, evything) take the same cover plate.  So you really need 2 *switch* 1 Decora.   And Decora was a *brand* in the 70s(?) which invented this scheme and probably had exclusive rights for a good while.  I know all the trendy homes had Decora...

Comment: @Harper -- it's a brand of Leviton (still)

Answer (score 1):

Your wall combination isn't too obscure (toggle/toggle/decorator), so you should be able to get a single plate to do that.  But if you have some other odd combinations, they can be harder to find.  Hera are some alternatives:

- Modular plates

[image]
[image]

It doesn't look as good as a single plate, but you can buy individual "gang" plates that fit together in a line.  You buy the two end plates and as many center plates as necessary.  Do a search for "center gang" at your supplier and you should find them.   If someone went crazy and gave you a switch/outlet/dial/decorator in a row, you can build your own covers.

- Inserts

[image]

You can get a n-gang plate with all decorator openings pretty easily.  Then, you can use inserts in them for anything else (like a traditional toggle switch).

- Custom

Never used them, but found a few places easily that will sell switch plates to order.  To be considered if the look of the other solutions doesn't cut it.

Answer (score 0):

You need a 3 gang decora cover. If tho other 2 switches are old style toggles they will need to be updated to the decor style.

Comment: As @brhans linked in a comment, there are covers which mix the Decora and old style in various configurations

Comment: Decora in the middle is probably not one of them, unless you really look.  OTOH between Tormach, Shopbot and 3D printing (tough enough for switchplates) you should be able to get *anything*.