# Where to aquire rubber bushings?

Tags: repair, appliances, rubber

Where can one order unusually-sized rubber bushings? A washing machine uses a 17mm OD, 4mm ID, 10mm length rubber bushing that is not available locally. I am aware of [McMaster](https://www.mcmaster.com/) but once I select any of the relevant parameters from the faceting menu, all other relevant options disappear. In any case, McMaster does not ship outside the US.

If had to make my own bushing, how might that be done? Would using a drill press result in an accurate bushing? Drill an OD hole, then fill it with silicon, then to put an ID drill upside down in the press and push that into the silicone. Is there a better way?

I realize that this is a borderline OT question, but it seems [to be allowed](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as in fact I did ask a local home contractor and this is related to the repair of a home appliance. Also, this [similarly-worded question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/126119/where-can-i-order-a-cover-plate-for-two-light-switches-and-one-humidity-sensor) is on topic, A-B question not withstanding.

Comment: google `rubber feet` and look at the pictures ... rubber winemaking plugs (corks) could also work

Comment: @jsotola Thank you. All the rubber feet I see are tapered, I don't think they will sit properly. But it might be a start if I have to fashion something.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, appliance repair parts are most easily found at an (these days, mostly online) appliance repair parts specialist dealer, as they are not generally "standard" parts (or if they were, you already found those ones by other means.)

Another option (if you just can't find one) is to make your own replacement part using something like silicone rubber that you can form yourself and let cure.

Comment: Thank you. I had considered making my own bushing, but I do not see how to get the OD and the ID exactly lined up. Perhaps with a drill press, to drill an OD hole, then fill it with silicon, then to put an ID drill upside down in the press and push that into the silicone. I suppose that should be another question.

Comment: Could work. Might also look for a rubber hose with the correct diameters (4mm ID, 6.5mm wall thickness) that you can cut a chunk off of. But that might not be easy to find either.

Comment: The hose idea is terrific! Online, I've found 17/12 mm hose, then 12/7mm hose, then 7/4mm hose. I'll see if I can source them locally, and I'll use silicon sealant between them. I only hope it remains strong enough once assembled. Thank you for the idea!

Comment: make your own from thermoset elastomer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2_0BYvTkZ0o

Comment: @Jasen: Thank you, I might see if I can find something similar locally.